# Having trouble compiling an ultimate tic tac to code I found because it is in a different coding language than what I am learning

Tags: c#, compilation

I have a code that I want to run  (mega tic tac toe code) that I got from the description of a video, however its in a different language that i am used to (Im learning java and the code is in C#) so I don't know how I should go about compiling this code. I messed around with some of the more well known compilers like visual studio and mono, however both seemed confusing to me as I am used to the eclipse compiler for java. Here is the video I am referring to. the code should be in the description of the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJ3TQdgkfBQ&t=366s.
Please let me know any tips or solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile the program with Visual Studio 2019 (Community Edition will be good)

The published github is not friendly...you have to create the project from scratch, follow those steps

- Create a new WPF project (WPF App (.NET Framework))
- Copy all files in the project folder
  (overwrite MainWindow.xaml and MainWindow.xaml.cs)
- Add all .cs file
  to the project (right click on project name -> Add -> Existing Item
  -> select .cs files)
- Build and run

Comment: thanks for the advice. Visual studio 2019 just finished installing and it looks like there are multiple wpf options. should i choose anything specific?